# How to create/generate vehicles from veins instead of SUMO

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Currently, I am generating vehicles from SUMO and importing into veins. However, now I want to use large number of vehicles (from 100 to 1000) and I want their random generation (e.g., random start time and random speed).

Can anyone help that i) how can I create/generate vehicles from veins instead of SUMO? and ii) how to randomly select start time and speed of vehicles?

Best Regards,
Yasir

Comment: Why don't you create an appropriate scenario in SUMO?

Comment: I already have create the scenario in SUMO. However, now instead of generating vehicles in SUMO for my scenario, I want to generate vehicles in veins because I want randomness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIVehicleInserter.ned was designed for. Whenever the number of active vehicles in OMNeT++ is less than a configured number, it starts a new vehicle using one of the existing route definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much @Christoph. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to generate route files with random seed/random start time.
Refer to **runner.py** file in https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/tests/complex/tutorial/traci_tls/runner.py and to the tutorial in https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic_Lights.html